# How are these definite integrals equivalent? $ \int_0^\infty B'(x)S'(t-x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^t B'(t-x)S'(x)dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been told that the following integrals are equivalent but I cannot figure out how:

$ \int_0^\infty B'(x)S'(t-x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^t B'(t-x)S'(x)dx $

Are there some rules on changing limits that I can apply to transform the first one to the second one?

Comment: Substitute $y = t-x$, then rename $y$ to $x$.

Comment: Managed to sort it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we substitute $ y = t -x \Rightarrow x = t-y $ we get

$$ \int_0^{\infty} B'(x)S'(t-x) \ dx = \int_{t}^{-\infty} B'(t-y)S'(t-(t-y)) d(t-y) = -\int_t^{-\infty} B'(t-y)S'(y) \ dy = \int_{-\infty}^t B'(t-y)S'(y) \ dy = \int_{-\infty}^t B'(t-x)S'(x) \ dx $$

Notes :

$$ \int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_a^b f(y) \ dy $$

$$ -\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_b^a f(y) \ dy $$

Comment: Thanks. How does the $d(t-y)$ transform into $-dy$?

Comment: $ \frac{d}{dy} (t-y) = -1 $

Comment: Ah yes! The very last step - I assume that is down to your first note - is that just a general rule?

Comment: yes $ {}{}{}{}{} $

Answer (score 0):

Let $t-x=y=>(t-x)'dx=dy<=>-dx=dy$.

For $x\to \infty =>y\to -\infty$.

For $x=0=>y=t$.

So we have that $\int_0^\infty B'(x)S'(t-x) dx =\int_{-\infty}^t B'(t-y)S'(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^t B'(t-x)S'(x)dx$